# PHP array and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is my current code:

```
$exceptions = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $opens = $row['opens'];
    $closes = $row['closes'];
    $joined = array($opens, $closes);
    $exception = join('-', $joined);

    $exceptions[] = array (
        $row['date'] => array($exception),
    );

}
```

Which gives:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [06/09] => Array ( [0] => 01:00-22:00 ) ) [1] => Array ( [06/10] => Array ( [0] => 01:00-22:00 ) ) )
```

But I'm aiming for this because the plugin requires this form:

```
Array ( [06/09] => Array ( [0] => 01:00-22:00 ) [06/10] => Array ( [0] => 01:00-22:00 ) )
```

Is there a way to rearrange the array to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assumptions
//  1. You have `$first_exception` within scope
//  2. You have `$rows` within scope
$exceptions = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    //  Assumption: `$row` has key `date`
    $exceptions[$row['date']] = array (
        $first_exception
    );
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with the exact code. The $exception is within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $exceptions = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $exceptions[$row['date']] = array ($first_exception);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this code. And try to read about arrays http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

```
$exceptions = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $exceptions[$row['date']][] = array($first_exception);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? It is not generating output as expected. PS. I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @BhavikShah ok, but this is the way, when if you have several exceptions in one day you'll have all them in result.

Comment: I guess, you are right on that part. But, it was not asked for in question.

Comment: @BhavikShah for example, you are developing service, you know that in some part of process could be issues, but you won't fix it because it is not part of a story at this time? Nope ;)